# View posts by author not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, mongodb

There is data in the MongoDB database, its just not being displayed on the front-end

Below is the section of code that deals with the display of posts on the profile screen, but its not displaying...

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

Thank you in advance.

```
<% posts.forEach(function(post) { %>
      <a href="/post/<%= post._id %>" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <img class="avatar-tiny" src="<%= post.author.avatar %>">
        <strong><%= post.title %></strong> on <%= post.createdDate.getMonth() + 1 %>/<%= post.createdDate.getDate() %>/<%= post.createdDate.getFullYear() %>
      </a>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: perhaps output/log the contents of the posts variable before the forEach, also log the post object inside the loop to see it's contents to get some clues about where the problem might be. Also you might want to check if getMonth() etc are used against a date object ie, let createdDate =  new Date(post.createdDate); then use createdDate.getMonth()

Comment: When i  <%= console.log(posts) %> it shows me an empty []

Comment: Yeah, make sure you fix the upstream code and it has data, at least now you know where to troubleshoot. Once you get the data going, make sure you also check the second suggestion I made in case there is an error that the date functions don't exist.

Comment: The Problem is fixed I made a mistake in mode/User.js  _id: userDoc.data.id,  it should look like this:_id: userDoc.data._id